# Add subview to changing location in main view in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, underscore.js

So I'm tinkering with Backbone.js right now and can't figure out something. So I've got an HTML list which is my main view in backbone. I declare each subview as an li element which I append to the main list.

Each li item is contenteditable. When the user presses the 'enter' key within one li element, I want to add a new li element just below the one within which the user keyed 'enter' from.

When the user presses the 'tab' key, I want to add another list (ol element) to the current li to create a nested list.

My problem is how do I know from the main view in which subview the 'enter' or 'tab' keys have been keyed in so that I can insert after or append the new element to it?

My code so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/the_archer/2p7u4bdj/2/

Initially, when the list is empty, there's a default "Sample" li item added to the ol element, resulting in the following structure:

```
<div class="dd" id="nestable3">
    <ol class="dd-list">
         <li data-id="1408256371250" class="dd-item dd3-item">
              <div class="dd3-content">Sample</div>
         </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

On pressing the enter key within the the first li "sample" I need to insert another li following the li within which the enter key was pressed resulting in this:

```
<div class="dd" id="nestable3">
    <ol class="dd-list">
         <li data-id="1408256371250" class="dd-item dd3-item">
              <div class="dd3-content">Sample</div>
         </li>
         <li data-id="1408256371251" class="dd-item dd3-item">
              <div class="dd3-content">Sample 2</div>
         </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

On pressing the tab key within the sample li from above, I want to append a new sub list within the li, making a nested list like so:

```
<div class="dd" id="nestable3">
    <ol class="dd-list">
         <li data-id="1408256371250" class="dd-item dd3-item">
              <div class="dd3-content">Sample</div>
              <ol class="dd-list">
                  <li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="1408256371252">
                      <div class="dd3-content">Item 16</div>
                  </li>
              </ol>
         </li>
         <li data-id="1408256371251" class="dd-item dd3-item">
              <div class="dd3-content">Sample 2</div>
         </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

As I said, my problem is how to attach event in such a way that I know which li has been keyed in, and how to create a new item and attach it to the required position. I'm a bit lost here.

I feel I need to do the positioning here in my code:

```
addOne: function (todo) {
    var view = new TodoView({
        model: todo
    });
    this.$(".dd-list").append(view.render().el);
},
```

However I can't figure out how to get the current li item being worked with here and then add a child or after it.

N.B: I'm working this code off the todo code of the Backbone.js todo example on the site.

Answer (score 2):

i suggest that take advantage from jquery event delegation and handle the events on your li elements in your main view, then access the target element and do whatever you need on it (append new elements or make it editable)

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

    // Instead of generating a new element, bind to the existing skeleton of
    // the App already present in the HTML.
    el: $("#nestable3"),

    // Delegated events for creating new items, and clearing completed ones.
    events: {
        "click il": "ToDoClicked",
        "keypress il": "ToDoKeyPress"
    },
    ToDoClicked: function(e){
        //you can create a ToDOView on $(e.target) and call whatever action you need
    },
    ToDoKeyPress: function(e){
        //you can create a ToDOView on $(e.target) and call whatever action you need
    }
});
```